# Issues with JavaScript highlighting and formatting in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, web-essentials

My colleague and I occasionally have issues with JavaScript in Visual Studio 2013:

[image]

After a while Visual Studio 2013 messes up the syntax highlighting and formatting of JavaScript. Whenever these graphical glitches occur, JavaScript files no longer get formatted as they should, and Edit > Format Document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) no longer works properly. New lines are no longer indented, braces are not placed correctly, etc.

The issue didn't occur with Visual Studio 201**2**. I am currently using the latest version of Visual Studio 2013, together with ReSharper 8.2 and Web Essentials 2013 (2.5.3).

I couldn't find anything similar online, so I'm asking it here on Stack Overflow. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

---

Edit: This might be unrelated, but sometimes I get this warning:

[image]

The JavaScript language service has encountered an error and has been shut down. Please save your changes, exit, and restart Visual Studio.